# How to avoid Exif data rotating images automatically after upload?

Tags: media

an image has been taken upside down, then rotated with any software, then uploaded to my Drupal website and it shows how it was originally taken because it read the Exif metadata.

Is there a way to avoid this?

or, if that's not possible,

how can I add a rotation Image Style drop down that the editor can select when creating the node?

Based on the picture preview, after uploading the picture, the editor would select an Image Style that would set the orientation of the picture right. if the picture is upside down, the editor could selec

Comment: How was image rotated? By changing EXIF orientation, or by altering real data and leaving orientation in place? Also, please read [this article](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/) - no module will be able to correctly interpret EXIF orientation, because there are too many "correct", widely used but contradicting interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this article](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/) - no module will be able to correctly interpret EXIF orientation, because there are too many "correct", widely used but contradicting interpretations. Even biggest brands have problems with this. **Even if your site will not rotate image, browser still can.**

To go around this problem, you can use [Formatter Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/formatter_field) module:

> For example, say you have a page node with an image field. Normally, you would select an image style as the formatter, and all page nodes would use that same image style. With this module, you can add a formatter field to page nodes, which is hooked up to the image field. Then when the node is created or edited, the image style can be selected per-node.

It's officially still in beta, but that's the best solution I know if you have no control over user's uploads. If you are the only one who uploades, just strip EXIF data (at least orientation part) and make sure you save your files without any, when preparing them for upload.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is now available. Simply download and enable module [Image EXIF Autorotate](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_exif_autorotate) and all uploads will be automatically rotated respecting the EXIF orientation.